# Error after installing React Navigation and gesture handler

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, android-emulator, react-navigation

I am new to react-native and trying to build an android app using react native in Android Studio for Windows. After I install react-navigation, follow all the steps in the react-navigation documentation, I run `react-native run-android` and I get this error in the command line:

```
PS C:\Users\comp\Desktop\work\reactnative\dansapp> react-native run-android
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'C:\Users\comp\Desktop\work\reactnative\dansapp\android\settings.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
Could not compile settings file 'C:\Users\comp\Desktop\work\reactnative\dansapp\android\settings.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  settings file 'C:\Users\comp\Desktop\work\reactnative\dansapp\android\settings.gradle': 3: unexpected char:
'\' @ line 3, column 133.
     s\react-native-gesture-handler\android')
                                   ^

  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:602:13)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:622:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\comp\Desktop\work\reactnative\dansapp\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:299:19)
    at buildAndRun (C:\Users\comp\Desktop\work\reactnative\dansapp\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:135:12)
    at isPackagerRunning.then.result (C:\Users\comp\Desktop\work\reactnative\dansapp\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:65:12)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)

PS C:\Users\comp\Desktop\work\reactnative\dansapp>
```

Does anyone know what this error is and how to resolve it? It seems to occur after I install react-navigation following these steps: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html

I have follwed the steps, including changing the `mainActivity.java` file. I also do not know what gradle is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: looks like you need to switch your \ for /

Comment: Can you insert the content of your settings.gradle file in /android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Known **issue** (see: [bug with react-native link in android and windows](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23176)), which will hopefully be fixed soon.

Jump into your settings.gradle file in */dansapp/android/* and replace...

```
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '..\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android')
```

...with...

```
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')
```